# How can the matrix A have this factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Part (a)
Show that any n×n real matrix, A, may be written as $QRQ^*$, where Q is unitary and R is upper triangular. Neither Q nor R needs to be real. Here $Q^*$ is the Hermitian conjugate of Q.

Part (b)
Give an example of a real 2×2 matrix A for which neither Q nor R is real.

Part (c)
Let D be any real symmetric n×n matrix and assume A is nonsingular. Show that there is a unique real symmetric matrix, C, so that $AC+CA^t=D$. 
Hint: use Part (a). Be sure to explain why C is real even though Q and R may not be. Here, $A^t$ is the real transpose of the real matrix A.

My work:

For part(a), I think that we can consider the vector space as an inner-product space, and perform a change-of-basis; in particular, we can change the standard basis to an orthonormal basis, and then represent A in a new matrix, with respect to the orthonormal basis.  This is achieved by the Gram-Schmidt process.  Then, writing out the similarity transformation to get the new matrix, we have $$Q^*AQ = M$$

(The columns of matrix Q contain the orthnormal basis vectors.)

However, I don't see any reason why M should be upper triangular.  A discussion of eigenvectors and eigenvalues would help, but there's also no reason to assume why A would have any eigenvalues.

Any hints are welcome :-)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is actually Schur's Unitary Triangularization theorem. (See Matrix Analysis by Horn & Johnson.) Let $x$ be a unit eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. Extend $\{x\}$ to an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb F^n$, say $\{x, u_2, \ldots, u_n\}$. Form the unitary matrix $U_1=[x\ u_2\cdots u_n]$. Consider the product $U_1^*AU_1=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1& *\\0&A_2\end{bmatrix}$. The next iteration considers $A_2$. Do this inductively.

(b) $\begin{bmatrix} 0& -1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}^*\cdot \begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$.

(c) If $A$ has real eigenvalues, then the orthonormalization process in (a) can be retricted to $\mathbb R^n$. Hence, instead of unitary, you have $U$ to be real orthogonal.

---

Realization about (c): Without other properties on $A$, the statement is false.  The statement is claiming that $AX+XA^T=D$ has a UNIQUE real symmetric solution. Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}$. Note that $X_1=I_2$ and $X_2=\begin{bmatrix}1& 1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ are two distinct solutions.

Comment: Hi @cchro, I was trying to go for a QR-decomposition proof, but now I see that there's a better way through your answer.  Can I ask you a question about  your part(a) answer?  How can you compute U*AU to be upper triangular so quickly?  Are you using a block matrix technique?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Lebron. I'm not sure if this will help, but let's look first at the first column of $AU_1$ which is $\lambda_1x$, right? If you multiply this by $U_1^*$ on the left, then each entry of the column that you'll get will be of the form $u_i^*Au_j$ or $x^*Au_j$. You will certainly get the first column  $\lambda_1e_1$ this way. As for the other columns, anything can happen. That's why we need to do an induction argument.

Btw, we don't expect to get the upper triangular form in the first $U_1$. That is why, we consider the submatrix $A_2$ in the next iteration.

Comment: Hi @cchro, I finally understand part(a)!! at about 6am last night.  Then I finally let myself go to sleep :-).  Reading your answer now, I realized you addressed all of the concerns very nicely and succinctly.  I had thought we should see the upper triangular form immediately.  But, proceeding by induction was crucial, and the upper triangular form starts to become apparent.

Comment: Hi @cchro, I just thought of this and wanted to ask you to follow up:  the proof assumes that this real nxn matrix must have an eigenvalue and hence an eigenvector.  But this guarantee is only true for complex linear operators.  So, are we necessarily assuming that our matrix is complex, with real entries, *and* that the ground field is complex?  Or, perhaps the ground field can be real or complex and is irrelevant in this proof -- and all that matters is the matrix can be viewed as complex (over the field of real numbers).  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Even though the ground field is $\mathbb R$, its algebraic closure $\mathbb C$ guarantees the existence of eigenvalues (which in general may be elements of $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$). I think the question implicitly assumes this. Otherwise, if we are going to work in $\mathbb R$ in the first place, the unitary matrix should have been replaced by real orthogonal matrix in the statement.

Comment: @LebronJames, I have figured something out about (c). Read my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks so much @cchro for your edited answer and additional comments.  Awesome counterexamples for part(c) :-)

Comment: @LebronJames, if you impose the assumption say, $A$ is a real matrix with positive eigenvalues, then from the theory of matrix equations, $AX+XA^T=D$ has a unique real matrix solution for any real matrix right hand side $D$. If you add the condition that $D$ is symmetric, then if $C$ is one solution, then $AC+CA^T=D=D^T=C^TA^T+AC^T=AC^T+C^TA^T$. Due to the uniqueness, $C=C^T$, that is, if a solution exists, then it has to be symmetric. 

(You may want to look at Lyapunov matrix equation.)

Comment: Hi @cchro, you seem to be making a statement that the mapping **C -> $AC + CA^t$ = D**, for a given D, and A, symmetric and nonsingular, respectively, is bijective, which is exactly what we want to show.  And if the solution exists, then it is forced to be symmetric, hence real, as required.  But, how does the additional assumption that A is real, symmetric, positive-definite (positive eigenvalues) help this mapping become bijective?  Perhaps it's something I am just overlooking...thanks,